# The placement of the word “seulement” in the following sentence

Tags: grammaire, sens, ordre-des-mots, adverbes, paroles-de-chanson

I was listening to the song *Tous les mêmes* by Stromae the other day, and in the second verse I noticed he sings the following;

> Moi je l'disais pour t'faire réagir, *seulement*
>   Toi, t'y pensais

Which as I understand means "me, I was *only* saying it to get a reaction from you. You, you were thinking about it (as in "and you were actually thinking about it"). But why is *seulement* placed in the end of the sentence here? Or is it just one way of saying it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/seulement/72435), **seulement**'s 4th meaning is the French equivalent of **however**.

Here are examples:

> Je t'ai attendu à la gare, seulement tu n'es pas venu…
>
> Moi, je le disais pour te faire réagir, seulement tu y pensais…

**Seulement voilà** means the same thing but is more insisting.

---

I'll try to explain what Stromae meant here:

It's all about what broken couples might have said. Especially the girls who would say something like "It's over" only to get more attention from the guys. **HOWEVER**, the guys can sometimes take it literally.

- "Quoi toi aussi tu veux en finir maintenant ? C'est le monde à l'envers" (Girl speaking to Guy, telling him that she wants to break up and he agrees or at least doesn't disagree).
- "Moi je le disais juste pour te faire réagir. Seulement, toi t'y pensais" (But she didn't really mean it **but** he still did take it as it is)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. This word was kinda confusing me for a while and it's nice get a good explanation from a real person.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's for the rhyme with "*maintenant*" two verse above.

Also putting "*seulement*" at the end is emphasing it.

Moreover there is a comma before "*seulement*", so maybe it can be understood as the beginning of the next line: "Seulement, toi, t'y pensais".

Which can mean: Alone, you were considering it (a breakup).

I also think that here "*seulement*" is looking like "*cependant*", which would mean:
I was just saying but you were really considering it.

Comment: Seulement here doesn't mean alone at all. Its only meaning, here, is **toutefois** = **however**

Comment: @BabyAzerty Really, it can mean however? I do recall seeing it this way somewhere but only in conjunction with "voilà" - "seulement voilà"

Comment: @noamb See my reply

Comment: @noamb *Seulement voilà* sounds horrible to me, a French Canadian. I don't know for other countries, but It really sounds weird to me.

Comment: Yes, it means however, sorry for the error.